# Selenium webdriver keeps getting stuck at random times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to scrape the homepage of about 10000 different websites, looking for contact information.
I already built the script, using selenium, and it works pretty well.
However, I'm getting a strange behavior with the webdriver... it just gets stuck, at random times, with no errors whatsoever, in this line:

```
 driver_pcr.get("https://" + url)
```

I'm not sure why. At first I thought it might be some issue with the website it's trying to open, but if I kill the execution, and restart on the same website, it gets loaded and scraped without issues.
Any ideas on what could be causing this, and/or how to fix it?

Here's the driver definition I'm using:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver_pcr = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver_pcr.set_page_load_timeout(15)
```

Comment: Did you check the status code of site by request library ? Is it 200 response for this site where it's stuck  ?

Comment: Yes it is 200. As I said, it happens randomly... If I rerun my script starting from the website where it got stuck, it now loads it and scrapes it correctly... just to get randomly stuck again later on, in another up-and-running website

Comment: Put a `try-catch` around that line and add some debugging like printing `url`, etc. before the script closes.

Comment: Already did, but no exception is thrown when this happens... The except is never executed. I get the print right before the ".get"... but that's it. It just hangs. But, as I said, this only happens sometimes with no explanation.